# OR in left join slow down the sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization, query-performance

Below sql query is slow with OR in join:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT ara.AmenityID,ara.AmenityDescription,ara.FinalAmenityName 
FROM alliance_reservation_amenities ara 
LEFT JOIN alliance_reservation_property_amenities rpa 
ON ara.AmenityID=rpa.AmenityID 
LEFT JOIN hotel_amadeus_properties_amenities apa 
ON ara.AmenityID=apa.AmenityID 
LEFT JOIN hotel_search_result_amadeus hsr 
ON rpa.PropertyID=hsr.AlncPropertyID  or apa.Property_ID=hsr.Property_ID 
WHERE SESSIONID='ddm6ln25n4snjiaqabfa8nnleqhhkq1mkea4560a9lmid8qo4kr1' 
AND userID=3108 and display = 1 
AND hsr.Search_Category !=2 
AND ara.AmenityID IN (9000206,9001587,119,9001596,9001679,9000505,9001036,9001652,
9001654,121,9001256,9001524,132,9001583,9000132,9000133,9001090,9001597,102336,9000807,
9001527,9001528,9001529,9001656,9001657,9000148,9000523,9000524,9000525,9000526,9000558,
9000962,9001024,9001051,9001098,9001099,9001292,9001459,9001462,9001593,9001681,9001682,
9001688,9001689,9001690,9001714,9001731,142,130986,130987,130988,130989,9001068,9001104,
9001694,9001695,9001716,9000190,9001145,9001715,9000527,9000752,9000754,9000755,9000836,
9001027,9001375,9001425,9001426,9001718,73,9000195,9000682,9001153,9001723) 
GROUP BY rpa.AmenityID ORDER BY ara.AmenityDescription ASC
```

[image]

Working correct without OR in join:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT ara.AmenityID,ara.AmenityDescription,ara.FinalAmenityName 
FROM alliance_reservation_amenities ara 
LEFT JOIN alliance_reservation_property_amenities rpa 
ON ara.AmenityID=rpa.AmenityID 
LEFT JOIN hotel_amadeus_properties_amenities apa 
ON ara.AmenityID=apa.AmenityID 
LEFT JOIN hotel_search_result_amadeus hsr 
ON rpa.PropertyID=hsr.AlncPropertyID 
where SESSIONID='ddm6ln25n4snjiaqabfa8nnleqhhkq1mkea4560a9lmid8qo4kr1' 
AND userID=3108 and display = 1 
AND hsr.Search_Category !=2 
AND ara.AmenityID IN (9000206,9001587,119,9001596,9001679,9000505,9001036,9001652,9001654,
121,9001256,9001524,132,9001583,9000132,9000133,9001090,9001597,102336,9000807,9001527,
9001528,9001529,9001656,9001657,9000148,9000523,9000524,9000525,9000526,9000558,9000962,
9001024,9001051,9001098,9001099,9001292,9001459,9001462,9001593,9001681,9001682,9001688,
9001689,9001690,9001714,9001731,142,130986,130987,130988,130989,9001068,9001104,9001694,
9001695,9001716,9000190,9001145,9001715,9000527,9000752,9000754,9000755,9000836,9001027,
9001375,9001425,9001426,9001718,73,9000195,9000682,9001153,9001723) 
GROUP BY rpa.AmenityID ORDER BY ara.AmenityDescription ASC
```

[image]

Can anyone help me with this what causing the first sql query to slow?

Comment: Does the result is same? It doesn't if there is extra column other than the first on clause

Comment: The or condition is only one of the problems with this query. Your group by is against the sql standards, your left joins do not make any sense, since you do not select from any of the right hand side tables and your where clause is likely to turn some if not all the left joins into inner joins.

Comment: @James first query with OR is slow down the server and yes returns the same out put.

Comment: @Shadow can you guide how it can be improved.. without removing any tables as they all are linked with columns?

Comment: I can't because no idea what the query is supposed to do and how any changes to it will affect the returned resultset.

Comment: you can try to do a union of the same query and divide "LEFT JOIN hotel_search_result_amadeus hsr 
ON rpa.PropertyID=hsr.AlncPropertyID  or apa.Property_ID=hsr.Property_ID " into the sigle left joins.

Comment: Qualify all columns used in a `JOIN` by the relevant table name or alias.  For example, what table is `SESSIONID` in?